# Altering thousands of records every page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance, optimization

I am starting to think about my new project and I've found a couple of speed issues, so I hope you can help me with selecting a good and elegant way to code it.

Each user has in the database records of "places" he has visited. Each place has "schools" - a number of schools in this particular place. Each school has classes. Each class may end its "learning year" at different times, so it's number should increment if date is >= end of learning year.

So we have such a database:

"places" table:

```
place | user_id | 
----------------- 
1     |   4     |
2     |   4     |
```

User no 4 visited place no 1 and 2

"schools" table:

```
school | place |
----------------
5      |   2   |
6      |   2   |
```

Place 2 has two schools - with id 5 and 6.

"class" table:

```
class | school | end_learning | class_number
---------------------------------------------
20    |   5    | 01.01.2013   |   2
21    |   5    | 03.01.2013   |   3
22    |   5    | 05.01.2013   |   4
```

School 5 has 3 classes with ids 20, 21, 22. If date is greater than 01.01.2013, the class number of class 20 should be incremented to 3 and end learning date changed to 01.01.2014. And so on.

And now we got into the problem - if there is 1000 places, each with 100 schools, each with 10 classes we got 1000000 records. It's a lot. Because all I have presented is just a simple example I have to consider updating whole database every time user refreshes the page so I'm afraid it might be laggy on that amount of records.

I also can serialize class into one field in school table:

```
school | place | classes
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
5      |   2   | serialized class 20, 21, 22 with end_learning field and class number
6      |   2   | other serialized classes from school 6
```

In that case I get 10 times less records but each time I have to deserialize data, check dates and if it's less than now alter it, serialize and save to database. The second problem is that I have to select all records from db to manipulate them not only all those need to be altered.

I am also thinking about having two databases: One with records that might need change in further future, and second that might need change in next 24hrs (near future). Every 24hrs all the classes which end learning in next 24 hrs are moved to "near future" db so every refresh of the page works on thousands of records, not hundreds of thousands or millions. Instead of that it works on millions of records (further future) to create "near future" table only once per day.

What do you think about all those database schemas? Maybe you have a better idea?

Comment: Re-think it. You shouldn't have to update your database every page refresh. I think this is your problem *"Each class may end "learning year" in different moment so it's number should increment if date is >= end of learning year"* Why should its number increment?

Comment: its number should increment because whan particular date happens you are no longer a pupil of class 2 but becaome a pupil of class 3. Ofcourse the example is just example - project isnt event about classes or schools - just made it like this to clearly describe need of data storage

Comment: I'm not sure you've demonstrated why records need to change when a page is visited. If a date passes X, then any availability of classes are presumably the same for all users. So, just do these queries once per day, on a schedule, for all site visitors.

Comment: You'll find your databases easier to follow (as will others) if you have a consistent naming convention on your primary and foreign keys. I suggest `id` for all primary keys, and `<table>_id` for all foreign keys. You've used `user_id`, which is good, but not done the same for school and place. (I realise this is just an example, but the point stands - make your questions easy to follow!)

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand the business logic or data model you outline - but I will assume you have thought this through.

Firstly, RDBMS solutions like MySQL are really, really good at managing large numbers of records, as long as the data you are working with is relational. As far as I can tell, you will be searching across many records, but only updating a few (a user will only be enrolled in a limited number of classes); I don't see this as a huge problem.

Secondly, it's nearly always better to go with the "standard" relational model until you can prove it doesn't meet your performance needs than to go for "exotic" solutions at the start off (I class your serialization and partitioning solution as "exotic" for the purpose of this answer). A lot of time and energy has gone into optimizing performance of SQL; if there were a simple alternative, it would be part of the standard solution. There are, of course, points at which the standard relational model doesn't scale (Facebook-size traffic, for instance), or business domains where the relational model doesn't really fit (documents, graphs). However, all the alternatives have benefits and drawbacks just like "standard" MySQL.

Thirdly, the best way to deal with possible performance issues is, well, to deal with them. In code. Build a test rig, create a schema according to the relational model, populate it with test data (e.g. using [DbMonster](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbmonster/)), throw some load at it (e.g. using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)) and tune your schema and queries to prove your situation doesn't fit the standard solution. Only go for something exotic if you really can prove that you can't play nice with standard, relational database stuff.